# Пунктуация. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, смысл

**Соответственно, недопонятому нашим обществом человеку довольно сложно, а порой невыносимо, жить.**

Правильно ли расставлены запятые? А также можно как-то упростить данное предложение по смыслу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

*Соответственно, недопонятому нашим обществом человеку довольно **сложно, а порой невыносимо жить.***

По грамматике вопросов нет, но одна запятая лишняя.

**Грамматический разбор**

Предложение односоставное безличное, сказуемое составное глагольное: сложно, (а порой) невыносимо жить.

Вспомогательная часть сказуемого выражена однородными модальными наречиями: сложно, невыносимо. Структурный дифференцирующий элемент «а порой» относится ко второму наречию и рассматривается как единое сочетание, поэтому там нет обособления.

**Текстовые примеры:**

(1)Читаю «Доктора Живаго», роман мной недооцененный и **недопонятый** в ту пору внешних страстей. [Давид Самойлов. Памятные записки (1971-1990

Рабле – одна из величайших **недопонятых** фигур эпохи Реформации.

Кто-то всегда чувствует себя невидимым или **недопонятым.**

(2) Почему невроз и психологическую проблему **очень сложно, а порой невозможно преодолеть** с помощью рационального понимания их причин.

К ним **тяжело, а порой и вовсе невозможно подступиться**, если это происходит вопреки их желанию.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (стилистическая правка)

*Соответственно, недопонятому нашим обществом человеку довольно слОжно, **а порой и просто невыносимо жИть.***

**Пояснение.** Предложение дополнено для увеличения объема последней фразы, тогда более обосновано выглядит пауза, обозначенная второй запятой.

Comment: Я бы оставил запятую. Запятая не ставится, если второе важнее, чем первое (так в примерах Розенталя). Здесь же у второго "порой", то есть это менее важно, потому что не так часто. Оно похоже на вставку, его можно в конец переставить, и так было бы лучше. Как-то во втором примере не так, может, потому что там смысловая однородность (*сложно и невозможно*).

Comment: Лучше – хуже... Вы грамматику разбирайте. У меня сочетание  "а порой " дифференцирует второе предикативное наречие.  А у вас что? А вы   запятой отделяете основной инфинитив  "жить" от модальной части  «довольно сложно, а порой невыносимо». Или что у вас?

Comment: У меня обособленный оборот.

Comment: Сказуемое: довольно сложно жить.  А оборот  как называется и какое отношение к этому сказуемому имеет.  У каждого оборота есть своя синтаксическая роль

Comment: Вставочный оборот. Важно то, что сложно, а другое на второстепенном плане. У вас всё на одном плане, а это не сильно логично, потому что говорится о важном, а потом о менее важном. Обычно порядок обратный. Если бы там было "а чаще всего", то да.

Comment: Если главная задача предложения в том, чтобы сказать о невыносимости, то нужен ваш вариант. В моём это не сильно важно.

Comment: А у вас что, собственная грамматика или так обходитесь.  Есть такой языковой  вариант "пиджин" со свободной грамматикой, вы нам такой предлагаете? Короче, каждое предложение должно иметь  нормированную грамматику. А все семантические проблемы решайте в рамках разрешенной формы,ага?

Comment: "Собственная" к грамматике не применимо. Если вы чего-то не знаете, это не значит, что оно не существует.

Comment: Да я-то при чем? Вы мне в книжечке покажите, ссылочку дайте, примеры приведите, вот тогда я вас уважать буду. Мы же цивилизованные люди,  по законам должны жить. Кстати, кто это у нас ушел, не знаете, почему очки списывают?

Comment: Вчера у Розенталя читал, там хорошие примеры, а сегодня уже найти не могу. Если увижу, то предоставлю. Но так даже логически получается: то, что важнее всего в предложении, идёт на переднем плане, такое не кидают в обособленный оборот, вставку, ведь при изъятии существенный ущерб смыслу, о таком не забывают и потом (в уточнении/добавлении) не досказывают. А если не важно, то его можно и обособить. Или вы не согласны? Это точно так. Другое дело — художественные обособления с целью подчеркнуть, но это вещь весьма специфическая. И там нет противительных союзов.

Comment: У меня 20 очков списало. Тот, что задал вопрос про кнопку, ник тоже удаляется, и не узнать уже. Но очки за галочку не списывают, по всей видимости.